# Placement of USB/UART converter for robustness and noise immunity: long USB cable or long EIA-422 cable

Tags: usb, noise, uart, serial, rs422

Consider the very common case of communication between the UART peripheral of a microcontroller and a PC, using a USB-UART converter such as are available from FTDI and others<sup>[1]</sup>.

If there's a non-trivial length of cable, then the characteristics will change depending on whether the conversion to USB is placed near the PC or the MCU.

1. Place converter near MCU.  UART link is short (may be TTL-level single-ended signals) and USB link is long.
2. Place converter near PC.  UART link is long (should be RS-422/EIA-422 differential pairs) and USB link is short.

USB, like EIA-422, uses differential signalling to reject common-mode noise.  But which is the better choice for a multiple meter run of rugged cable?

I presume the advantage goes to EIA-422 because it is compatible with a wide range of twisted pair cables, while USB signalling requires specific impedance matching.  On the other hand, USB is pervasive so cables with rugged protective jackets do also exist.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> All the converters I'm interested in use either 12 Mbps or 480 Mbps.

For the purposes of this question, let's assume a UART rate of 3 Mbaud, putting us well within the capability of full-speed (12 Mbps) USB.

For the purposes of this question, let's assume a cable length range of 2 to 10 meters.

Yes, single-ended serial, whether TTL or EIA-232, can achieve 3 Mbps in a quiet environment, but they are quite sensitive to interference.

Comment: How much is a non-trivial length of multiple meters of wire then? 1,2,3,4 or 5 meters, or more? Which USB protocol is used, 1.5, 12, 480 MBPS or something else?

Comment: @Justme I'd assume 12, but that's actually a good question -- I don't know offhand, I haven't shopped around and maybe there are USB USARTs with >20Mbps capability; RS-422/485 is viable up to 20, 50Mbps even, after all. (That said, the "usual" FTDI etc. top out around 5Mbps, IIRC.)

Comment: So, how long are we talking? USB has a rather strict limit. If compliant cables are being used (with repeaters if necessary), it doesn't matter, it simply does what it does, up to that limiting length. RS-422/485 can go some km (give or take line condition / termination, and rate). Immunity is as specified; line length doesn't factor into it (or rather it does, in specific cases; but testing for any general case means, assume the worst regardless). And to clarify a common misconception: USB is at best "mostly" differential; it would be better to say differential with respect to ground/shield.

Comment: @TimWilliams By that logic, also RS485 and RS422 are just mostly differential as well.

Comment: @Justme Indeed!  They are "more differential" at least, but this too is a point often forgotten.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm confused, what is your definition of differential? USB has two conductors that switch in opposite polarity for signalling. Why is that not differential?

Comment: @TimWilliams: "It doesn't matter, it simply does what it does".   I disagree.  There will be a bit error rate, which is a function of the power spectrum of interfering electrical and magnetic fields.  Depending on error detection and correction codes, that will translate to a certain rate of undetected errors as well as discarded frames.  One doesn't have to necessarily calculate all these if one option is known to handle noise better.  It's good that you brought up that USB can need repeater/regenerators, because those have to be placed in the middle of the cable and protected from damage.

Comment: @BeB00: Not all symbols sent on USB have balanced opposite levels on D+ and D-.

Comment: @BeB00 Depends on USB version how it works, but up to and including 12 MBps, it's really just more like two ground-referenced 3.3V logic level signals twisted together, with some symbols sent non-differentially, even if most are sent differentially, and they are not differentially terminated. Not true differential like RS-485/RS-422/LVDS etc.

Comment: @BeB00 In addition to the SE0 symbol (both lines low), the common mode range is strictly limited to the supply rails (or for RS422/485, +12/-7V, maybe a bit more for enhanced receivers, or related standards like CAN which can be 20V or more).

Comment: You will always be limited to the allowable length of the USB cable.

Comment: @ScottSeidman True, and also limited to multiple USB cables if you use hubs between cables, or limited to active USB repeater cables of few tens of meters, or limited to few hundred meters with USB CAT5 extender boxes, or few kilometers with USB fiber extenders. But are these viable or cost effective options, unlikely.

Comment: Speaking of viable or cost-effective -- what level of immunity are we looking at here?  Commercial, industrial, specialized? What budget, and other constraints (do the cables need to be flexible or can we use rigid conduit?)? I can conceive of a system that will handle anything either way, but the question is really: in which direction do you need to optimize it?

Comment: @TimWilliams: Trying to avoid disclosures of any proprietary information, let's just say the cable needs to be deployed and respooled frequently in a crowded transportation hub so there will be all manner of innocent sources of interference in close proximity like cell phones, bluetooth, CD-to-radio repeaters, etc.  Potential also for malicious parties who would like to intermittently confound communication with sensors (from >10m distance, using any equipment that can be hidden in a personal vehicle).

Comment: In an active jamming scenario, uninterrupted operation is not required, but the breakdown in communication needs to itself be meaningful that there's intentional interference.  Budget is somewhat flexible -- $200/cable would be feasible but $40-50 would be desirable.

Comment: At this point I'm thinking EIA-422 signalling in a "flexible armor" rugged cable, with short and open-circuit detection and overload protection in hardware at both ends and forward error detection and retries in software.

Comment: Agreed, that sounds promising.

Answer (score 1):

The answer could be very simple.

You can buy ready made USB to TTL, USB to RS-485, USB to RS-422, and USB to RS-232 cables. Even directly from FTDI. Most of them have the USB chip right at the USB connector, as there are just cable and bare wires. The adapters with RS-232 on a DE-9 connector may better fit the USB chip at the DE-9 connector end.

USB has maximum length of 3 or 5 meters per cable segment depending on which USB version and speed is in question.

In practice, don't really count on it - I've seen a manual which tells users to use 1 meter or shorter cable to prevent problems - difficult to say do they know their device might not be the best, or do they suggest most PCs were not the best at handling USB, as there may be various quality and length differences of USB cabling inside a PC, for example from front panel to motherboard.

On the other hand RS-422 and RS-485 can hande up to 1200 meters, depending on implementation. RS-232 should go up to 15 meters without issues.

And the 3.3V TTL (CMOS really) adapter cable from FTDI works for 1 meter at 3 Mbps just fine. So for short lengths logic levels are no issue.

Comment: So your answer is "USB struggles with cables over a meter in a best-case environment, and even the converter manufacturer uses long serial / short USB so do the same"?

Comment: @BenVoigt No I did not say that. The thing is the USB chip with transceivers typically fits inside USB plug and there is just no other and cheaper place to put the chip except right at the plug from where cable/wires stick out. USB should work well for 2-3 meters just fine and if you need more than 2-3 meters you have to anyway use an active hub/repeater/extender if you need to much beyond one 2m cable.

Comment: "On the same circuit board as the MCU" is a viable option for converter chip placement, and there's also more than one place for a USB plug where the converter can be hidden -- right at the PC is one but also at the enclosure of the embedded device.

Comment: @BenVoigt It is a viable option if you want to work within USB cable limits or extend it with hubs. If you need up to 10 meters, that's at least two hubs with two 5 meter cables if you want USB, or active extender cable if you trust them. If you use USB to RS-485 or RS-422 adapter cable, regardless of where the USB chip is, just add suitable connectors and cables for getting far beyond 10 meters. Which is why many devices don't use USB for long cabling.

Comment: I never had problem with USB repeaters (even cheap ones). Max that I used was 20 m with data rate of 48 Mbps (+overhead) with no problems. Only problem was/is if you have bus powered device. In that case you can have problems even with much shorter cables.

Comment: 20m is about as far as I would go with active repeaters. Beyond 30m you start running into bus timing issues. I had huge trouble with 50m link. It would just drop off the bus after 5 minutes, and wouldn't come back without restarting the computer.

Comment: @Rokta Right, so even if you never had any problems, excluding the scenario of perfectly normal thing to have where it failed, they should work for everyone? Try running them 24/7 in a classroom setting where people need to plug their USB flash drive to a computer in the corner of the room

Comment: @user1937198 There are many different kinds of extender. Some repeat the traffic, some convert the protocol to something else like IP and these pretend you have a direct connection, albeit with some delay.

Comment: @Justme Which depends on the type of device you want to connect. Due to the nature of USBs half-duplex protocol, if you convert it to something else, you don't have a USB extender, you have a USB to whatever and whatever to USB convertor, because USB can't tolerate the delay at the protocol level. If you have something that isn't a standard device class, I wouldn't be confident in the converters, And in this scenario, you might as well just use RS-422 at the first conversion, rather than go through 3 converters with an unnecessary second USB leg.